# How many messages can an activemq topic hold with multiple durable subscribers?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I have multiple durable subscribers subscribed to a topic? How many messages can the topic hold? What is the maximum number of messages it can hold?

I am using KahaDB as persistence adapter. I am assuming it depends on the amount of memory that KahaDB has .Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It depends on the amount of memory available to KahaDB as well as the size of each message.

ActiveMQ has a strategy to page down exceeding memory to disk, so that available Java heap won't be a limit. However, paging message has performance implications so every scenario has to be tested.

Read up on [message cursors](http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html) for details